# How do I break in a Win32 API function based on the function's parameters?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, debugging

I'm debugging a mixed .Net / native application with VS2010, and I'm trying to determine if / when a particular BSTR gets freed.  Based on this question: [Debug Break on Win32 Api functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080624/debug-break-on-win32-api-functions) I've figured out how to set a breakpoint in SysFreeString, but it gets called A LOT.  I'd like to set a condition to have it only break when the particular string I'm interested in gets freed.

It looks like the address of the string gets pushed onto the stack, but I can't figure out how to dereference the stack registers to figure out if it's my string or not.  I tried putting something like `[esp] == 0x001ADCAC` (where 0x001ADCAC is the address of the string I'm interested in) in the breakpoint condition, but that did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out!  I put the following into the condition for the breakpoint:

```
DW esp+4 == 0x001ADCAC
```

and it worked.  DW is the debugger's equivalent to "dword ptr".  All of the "Assembly language expressions" are listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56638b75.aspx

This would have worked as well:

```
*(unsigned long*)(esp+4) == 0x001ADCAC
```